# Selecting all direct children of a <ul> element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>One</li>
  <ul class="submenu">
   <li>Apple</li>
   <li>Orange</li>
  </ul>
 <li>Two</li>
  <ul class="submenu">
   <li>Pear</li>
   <li>Banana</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to select only the first children of the top level `<ul>` element (in this case "One" and "Two") with just CSS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the child selector `>`:

```
ul > li { font-weight: bold; }
```

The only problem is that this doesn't work in IE6. See this list of [CSS selectors and browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

If you need to support that browser you'll have to do something like this.

```
ul li { font-weight: bold; }
ul li li { font-weight: normal; }
```

This will be relatively straightforward in some situations and completely unworkable in others. If you find yourself in a difficult situation you may need to interpose some classes to make it easier.

Comment: Won't this also select the fruits? I'd like it just select "One" and "Two". Perhaps I'd have to specify some classes if I want to be that specific.

Comment: @soliah, cletus's answer is correct based on the question posed. As always, Test and see for yourself if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul > li
```

But it won't work in IE6. Here is a nice list of selector support in IE versions:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/

The simplest way to explicitly target them is to give them a separate class name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are not worried about using jQuery, you can get over IE6 compatibility issue by using jQuery css support.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup's wrong. It should be:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>One
  <ul class="submenu">
   <li>Apple</li>
   <li>Orange</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Nested lists appear inside the preceding li element